# How to correctly authenticate user based on bearer token in Web API 2

Tags: android, oauth, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API 2 back-end for my Android mobile app. I want to use OAuth authentication (in this case Google login), so I signed in on mobile app, got a valid access token from Google and include it in authorization header within every request to Web API back-end:

```
Authorization: Bearer [token value]
```

This is my Web API ConfigureAuth method:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
app.UseGoogleAuthentication();
```

As I understand, app.UseGoogleAuthentication() + OWIN should do the trick: extract access token from incoming request and use it to authenticate the user, am I right? But it didn't happen, incoming request was denied as unauthorized. So how can be this simple scenario achieved?

I've read a lot of articles on the topic, but everytime it discussed only scenarios using a browser as a client - that is not my case, I'm not using external cookies.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?